# Node.js NTLM HTTP Authentication, how to handle the 3 types

Tags: node.js, authentication, encoding, ntlm

I'm trying to get NTLM Authentication working w/ Node.js. I've been reading this ( http://davenport.sourceforge.net/ntlm.html#theNtlmMessageHeaderLayout ). I send the header and get a Base64 authentication header.

I tried converting it from Base64 to UTF8 by making a new Buffer with base64 encoding and then calling `toString('utf8')` which returns a string something like

`NTLMSSP\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0007ï¿½\bï¿½\u0000`

This is where I need help. I understand the NTLMSSP\u0000 is the null terminated signature, but and what the rest is *supposed* to indicate, but to me it's just garbage. It's unicode characters, but how am I supposed to get actual data out of that? I may be converting it incorrectly, which may be adding to my troubles, but I'm hoping someone can help.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at http://www.innovation.ch/personal/ronald/ntlm.html
What you receive is a Type-2 Message. The pages explains it in a very practical way. You have to extract the server challenge (nonce) and the server flags.

I just implemented a module for node.js to do just that: https://github.com/SamDecrock/node-http-ntlm

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at [NTLMAPS](http://ntlmaps.sourceforge.net/)?

You may be able to solve your problem by using it as a proxy server, but if you really want to implement NTLM auth in Javascript, then NTLMAPS provides lots of working code to study.

Answer (score 3):

Sam posted the best resource I've seen for understanding what's going on.

jclulow on GitHub seems to have implemented it in a Samba library he built.

Take a look here:
https://github.com/jclulow/node-smbhash
under lib\ntlm.js you can see how he's handled the responses.

Answer (score 2):

I've built client a couple of months ago using javascript, [ntlm.js](https://github.com/erlandranvinge/ntlm.js). Maybe that can help you get along. It was based on the documentation @ innovation.ch and Microsofts own official documentation (see the references on the github page).