# nodejs user system authentication

Tags: node.js, authentication

I'm a `nodejs` beginner and I have a question about authentication.
My goal is to have an authentication based on the operative system users where the server js run.
I read many article on passport and express framework, but all require the presence of a mongoDB and it was out of scope for my problem.

So my question is:
Is it possible in `nodejs` to interact with OS and write an authentication module for the OS users?

Comment: which OS do you mean?

Comment: Linux and Windows would be the best. Or at least one of them.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't know how to deal with the native authentication on Linux also I don't know if it is a good idea, but for some Windows-related points see my answer below. If you find it useful then read http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly how is it possible, but it *should be* possible.

Some links for Windows:

- [C# Corner: Vidya Vrat Agarwal, Understanding Windows Authentication in Detail](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/84c85b/understanding-windows-authentication-in-details/)
- [StackOverflow: Windows Integrated Authentication in node.js Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13949163/windows-integrated-authentication-in-node-js-client)
- [StackOverflow: NTLM authentication using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12140589/ntlm-authentication-using-node-js)
- [Windows → Dev Center - Desktop → LogonUser function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Addons Node.js Manual & Documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#addons_addons)

However, if you are new to `Node.js` then using [Windows Authentication strategy for Passport.js](https://github.com/auth0/passport-windowsauth) together with some MongoDB alternative (see [Stack Overflow: Lightweight Javascript DB for use in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233057/lightweight-javascript-db-for-use-in-node-js)) may be an easier way to go