# POST request from Node to another server with windows credentials

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, authentication

I am trying to send a post request to a service from my node server.
Node is running on http://localhost:3000. The method I am trying to reach is reachable through http://localhost:80/some/adress/business/layer/myMethod.

```
var options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    path: '/some/adress/business/layer/myMethod',
    port: '80',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
         'Content-type': 'application/json',
         'Content-Length': data.length
    }
};

var req = http.request(options, function (resu) {
    console.log('statusCode: ' + res.statusCode)

    resu.on('data', function (d) {
        console.log(d);
    });

    resu.on('error', function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
    });

    resu.on('end', function () {
        res.jsonp({ result: true });
        res.end();
    });
});

req.write("data");
req.end();
```

The request works fine, well more or less. I am getting a 401 status back. The question is: How can I send windows credentials from node to the named server running on localhost:80... ?

Comment: From HTTP protocol point of view, what kind of authentication information does `/some/adress/business/layer/myMethod` need?

Comment: It needs a NTLM authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the exact details of your setup, I can't be sure, but you probably need to use NTLM authentication. There are several libraries that do this for node. Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12140589/ntlm-authentication-using-node-js). Hope this helps!

Comment: I am pretty new to node and figured it out to run the server through learning by doing to be honest. What do you need to know in detail? And thank you for the provided link I will take a look at it.

Comment: I'm not an expert either, but in previous clients I've worked at, we used windows auth and NTLM worked for us. My disclaimer was more to the fact that I can't be 100% sure there isn't some other way to set things up on the back-end that would render my advice irrelevant